# How to fix rainbow like video with python-opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, video, raspberry-pi, debian-buster

I am trying to create a video monitoring system on my Raspberry Pi. The OS version is the latest Raspbian Buster.

I decided to move recently on Buster since it has just come out. Before I was on Stretch. It was working really fine. The only problem I got was that when I tried to increase my window size, the FPS was decreasing leading to a small latency. So that is why I moved to Buster to see if it was working better or if was a limitation due to the Raspberry Pi.

So here is my code:

```py
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture()

ret, im = cap.read()

while True:
  ret, im = cap.read()
  cv2.namedWindow('frame', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
  cv2.imshow('frame', im)
  key = cv2.waitKey(10)
```

This is what my expected output should looks like:

[image: expected output image]

This is my actual output:

[image: actual output image]

Do you have any idea of what the problem could be? And how to solve it?

Comment: I have a feeling it has something to do with your increasing window size code. You probably are not resizing correctly which leads to the rainbow image